# angularjs rest API Spring

Tags: angularjs, rest, api

i have a problem with rest API in angularjs.

web.xml

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>SpringServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.mycompany.xxxx.userInterface.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

SpringServlet.class

```
@Override
    public void init() throws ServletException 
    {
        super.init();
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
        SpringBeanReader.getInstance().setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        //SpringBeanReader.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getBean(")
    }
```

I have problems when I call api.

controller.js

```
.service('ApiCall', ['$http', function ($http){
    //Get All Employees
    this.getEmployees = function () {
        console.log('dentro service.js');
        return $http.get("/utenti/all"); 
    }   
}])
.controller("DataTable",['$scope','ApiCall', 
    function($scope,ApiCall){
        $scope.persons = ApiCall.getEmployees();

}])
```

Controller.class

```
@Path("/utenti")
public class UtentiController {

    @Path("/all")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")

    public JSONArray getAll() {
/****   code for JSON array ***/
    }
```

The code "$http.get("/utenti/all");" return error

```
HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]
Type Status Report
Message /foodplan/utenti/all
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: /foodplan/utenti/all??, where is puttin "/foodplan", because in code is "/utenti/all" not?

Comment: Sorry... the message is  Message /utenti/all ... Foodplan was a test